# Ghosting context menu clicks in WinXP

Tags: windows, display, context-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Menu command stuck on screen](https://superuser.com/questions/57016/menu-command-stuck-on-screen)

Let me preface by saying I have a lot of windows open most of the time, although not resource intensive ones, just browsers, ssh sessions, a music player, FTP client, Notepad++, IM clkients, etc. Anyway, I get a lot of weird visual "ghosting" type effects. For example when right-clicking and then selecting an option from a context menu the selected item will remain in view until I right click somewhere on the desktop. Same thing happens when selecting items from the File, Edit, etc. menu in various programs. I'm assuming this is just a result of a less than high quality video card (NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200), all the other hardware in the machine is newer higher quality, that specific video card was added after the fact for multiple monitors.

I have looked all over the web for solutions and have increased the number of GDI handles for Windows, reduced the hardware accelaration on the card, etc.

Any suggestions other than replace the card?

Comment: Check out http://superuser.com/questions/57016/menu-command-stuck-on-screen which I believe is the same issue.

Comment: potential duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/57016/menu-command-stuck-on-screen

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your graphics card.  Check your mouse with the same configuration in a different computer.  If the same thing happens, there is a fault in your mouse.  Or use some other mouse instead.  Or else format it.

Answer (score 0):

MrStatic Oct25 is right.  Inside that link has the solution:  Disable Fading Menu visual effects in the desktop Appearance settings of Windows in System Properties... Performance. Advanced.