# Windows 7 context menu not disappearing after selecting an option

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Persisting right click menu highlight](https://superuser.com/questions/119719/persisting-right-click-menu-highlight)

I have a very annoying problem for several days now. Whenever I open context menu in any application on my Windows and select any option it does not disappear correctly. The option I choose is always visiable and what's even more annoying it's beign displayed over any other application. The only solution I've found at the moment is to change a display resolution and restore it. That makes it disappear but it's very annoying because I have to do that always after using context menus. Is there any fix for this problem?

Comment: I answered a very similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/119719/