# Ghost images on Monitor from applications. Why do they happen and can you kill em off without a reboot

Tags: windows-7, display, notepad++, ghost-image

Take a look at the attached picture. There is a semi transparent "Ghost" file path from Notepad++. Notepad++ is not reunning. It was restarted normally several times but it has no bearing on the Ghost picture.
So it looks like it has gone "Zombie" and I wonder what's causing it. I disabled and enabled display - and pulled other ticks I could think of but its still there. Other that a reboot which'd make me LOOSE my work. Is there anything else out there that can get this out ( standby did not help ).
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should try this http://superuser.com/questions/556520/how-do-you-remove-ghost-menu-items-in-windows-7

Comment: Mr Slava !!! - TGI FRIDAYS to you .....Windows 7 is a newly modeled  home with  "false ceilings' and creepy little places  in it that are hard to approach and this is one of them . TY  for that wonderful link