# "Edit with Notepad++" stays in screen

Tags: windows, notepad++

After i did some editing with Notepad++ i noticed that the option thats in the menu when you right-click a file didn't go away. Does anyone how to get this away? Tried killing notepad and explorer, restarting isn't a option because i'm making a backup.

Picture for clarification

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try resetting the desktop window manager
Start > Run > and type

```
tskill dwm
```

Or kill it from the GUI task manager.
[image]

Comment: Hmm, it looks like its coming back everytime im using Notepad++, do you know a permanent fix?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://superuser.com/a/57021/155564
Apparently fade visual effects might cause this thing.

Comment: It seems to be that, after i've rebooted and applied your answer i don't get it anymore.