# How to solve this visual defect in window 7 instead of PC restart?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am using window 7 64-bit

Very often, I will have this visual defect problem on my screen like below:
[image: visual defect at wubdiw 7]

As you can see, there is a

```
Save as                                 Ctrl+Alt+S
```

floating on my screen.

This problem happens when I save some files.

The occurrence is random.

I solve this problem by restarting my PC.

But what could be the possible root case and how can I solve this defect without restarting my PC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Menu select item stuck on screen after context or command menu has closed](http://superuser.com/questions/57016/menu-select-item-stuck-on-screen-after-context-or-command-menu-has-closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Start -> Run -> type `tskill dwm`.

Answer (score 0):

Purely anecdotal; but I see this often too.

What I have found I can do is click the same menu / file / options menu that created the floating menu and select something. This seems to call the method or redraw to get rid of it.

So figure out which application causes the issue, and then when this happens perform the same operation that the original menu came from. Then select an action from that menu. Hopefully it works for you, like it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna sound absolutely stupid but just start arbitrarily closing and killing applications (non-essential ones of course).

Anecdotally; Chrome did it too me once and as I was closing up programs to shut down it randomly disappeared.

Next I've had MS Word do this to me, and just to try something (because it was really annoying me), I closed everything.
Failing that, I started killing superfluous programs from the `Task Manager` <sub>(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>)</sub> because I really didn't want to shut-down.
As soon as I killed Java it vanished.

If someone could explain this to me that'd be great, and hopefully it will help you.
A note for you, though; If you can get this to happen consistently (well, at least with the same menu/button on the same application) you might be able to submit a bug to the relevant developer(s).