# Windows balloon tip stuck on my screen during fade out

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-interface

A balloon tip is stuck/frozen on my screen and it overlaps every other graphical element. How can this be removed without rebooting?

You can see the graphical glitch on the following screen. Actually it's only the shade of the balloon tip:

[image]

Related thread, but does not solve my issue:
[Menu select item stuck on screen after context or command menu has closed](https://superuser.com/questions/57016/menu-select-item-stuck-on-screen-after-context-or-command-menu-has-closed)

Comment: Give this a shot from elevated command prompt --> `Taskkill /f /im "explorer.exe` and then press **Enter**... Then from that same command prompt type in "explorer.exe` and then press **Enter**... if that helps resolve without a reboot please let me know and I'll be happy to add as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: Does this happen with *all* balloon tips? A reboot does not fix this?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT: balloon tip is gone, but now my taskbar is gone, too. how can I let it reappear? edit: I just typed `"explorer.exe"` into the command line and everything is back to normal. thx!

Comment: Beta - Cool, I just added this as an answer for you to accept whenever you get to it since you confirmed that my suggestion corrected the problem. Let me know if there are further problems or questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can see the graphical glitch on the following screen. How can this
>   be removed without rebooting?

To correct a graphical glitch on the Windows desktop that a reboot of the machine typically resolves, you can just use [Taskkill](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) to kill `Explorer.exe` from running in memory, and then start a new instance of `Explorer.exe`—you can do both of these operations from an elevated command prompt with **Windows 7** (see below example).

---

### Command Line

<sub>*Run these from an elevated **Run As Administrator** command prompt and be sure to press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> after each command.*</sub>

```
:::: This kills explorer.exe from running in memory
TASKKILL /F /IM "Explorer.exe"
:::: This restarts a new instance of Explorer.exe in memory
Explorer.exe
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**Taskkill**](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)